# Should I be using Camera or Camera2?

Tags: android

If my gradle file has:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
```

But my Fragment.java file, underlines the Camera word.
Am I doing anything wrong? If I use Camera2 it comes as an error, and highlights it as red.

[image]

Comment: See this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272845/android-camera-camera2-apis

Comment: So i guess I will need to stick with the annoying warning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camera2 is added in API level 21. Your app will crash on devices with api levels 15-20. Use old Camera API.

Comment: Is it possible to remove android studio's annoying warning (underline)?

Comment: just add @SuppressWarnings("deprecation" ) annotation to your class or method where you are using deprecated APIs

Comment: Thanks, is this a Java/Android SDK thing, or a IDE?

Comment: This is JDK thing, and clever IDEs know how to understand it

Answer (score 1):

The [camera2 package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) was added in API level 21 to replace the old camera package. As you are targeting pre 21 APIs the camera2 package is not available yet. You will have to work with `camera` or upgrade to minSdk 21.

Comment: Is it possible to remove android studio's annoying warning (underline)?