# Camera 1 package on Android API level 23

Tags: android, camera, deprecated, face-detection

I want to make an Android App using face detection.

I've readed about Camera 1 and Camera 2 APIs.

Currently I'm using face detection with libraries from Google play services and taking picture with an Intent. But I would like to ensure that the app will recognize at least 1 face when user take the picture from my app.

I don't want to develop two classes with an interface to support both APIs
[Android Camera & camera2 API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272845/android-camera-camera2-apis/32519422#32519422)

So, the question is, is the android.hardware.camera supported on Android 6? I don't want to publish an app that fails on newer devices.

Some other idea to solve the deprecation of this API?

Another reason to change the library Google play services is becasue doesn't recognize many faces

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The old camera API still works on devices running Android 6. I haven't heard about any plans to discontinue it, although the new API is becoming the standard. The best way to "solve" the depreciation of the old API is start getting acquainted with the new one. It is a daunting task for a beginner, but there is no way around it. My suggestion is that you start from the official sample applications and learn from there.

Comment: This the url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.papulabs.designateddriver