# Call requires API Level 21 (getting camera2 to run on devices lower than 21?)

Tags: android

Noticed that my app is getting runtimeexceptions and arrayoutofboundsexception. I traced the problem to this area of my code

```
 mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get an error saying that "Call requires API Level 21  (current min is 14):android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager#getCameraIdList

What's the best way to fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiRTx.png)

Comment: Use camera 1.  There is no way to use camera2 below version 21.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28417458/1649353.

It clearly states that you need to use the old camera if you want to support older devices. Give it a try.