# Unable to create a surfaceview camera app that supports android 4.0 and above.

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-api

I'm planning to make a camera app that you can take a photo with a background image.
I guess there will be a  need to use a Surfaceview? But the main problem is since the Camera is deprecated 
there might be a need to use camera2 for android. I want to make a camera app in portrait mode but are there any
samples or tip? I googled but wasn't able to find a decent one. I would love to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with `Camera2` API, this link will help you understand basics.

[android-Camera2Basic(Github)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

---

> It is not necessary to use **`SurfaceView`** as you will see from code
>   that **`TextureView`** can also fulfill your requirement

Comment: Thank you but it wont support android os 4.0 right? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry that i can't help you much but you can join this discussion [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28417458/10271334) @Nancy

Answer (score 0):

The [HdrViewfinder](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder) sample app uses SurfaceView with camera2, though it doesn't lock itself into portrait mode.  But that's a relatively simple change.

Of course, camera2 was only added in Android 5.0, so if you need to support 4.0, you need to use the old camera API.