# How to use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.camera"

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

I am trying to use the camera plugin in flutter(for Image Picker from camera as the source) ,I understand that I need to have a min sdk version to 21 for using it,but when I see the error it also suggests that we can also override the plugin usage(which may result in runtime crashes)

```
 use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.camera" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

[image]
so can anyone point me in the right direction on How do I override it ?

Comment: what Image picker are you using? If it is third party plugin, why not just use the [official one](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)?

Comment: yes I am using the same official one image_picker v0.6.2+3

Comment: according to the source code of the official library. in [build.gradle](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/android/build.gradle) `minSdk` is set to 16.

Comment: I am not sure what's causing this problem. Unless you are also using `camera` plugin by flutter as well. it has a `minSdk` set to 21. which means your project should also match those contraints.

Comment: I am able to use the camera plugin if I set the minsdk version to 21,I just wanted to know if its possible to override bumping up the min sdk to 21, I want my app to support min sdk 16

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to override the plugin. Since the flutter team must always provide minimum SDK support as a platform and if they are not, it means there's no point. if you still modify the constraints then afterward you are on your own.  Nobody else can help you.

Comment: I'd suggest creating your own camera plugin in flutter for such cases, it'll help you find a way out of this or at least allow you know if you should override it or not.

Comment: What is the flutter sdk version you use ??

Answer (score 0):

Use

In AndroidManifest.xml

Also try to change Flutter SDK version to DEV if you use stable version.

Also check:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1598/files

Answer (score 0):

The camera plugin [uses](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/Camera.java) the [camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary), which is only available in API level 21 and newer.

Overriding this error (with `overrideTools`) will break your app for apps on API level 20 and below.

If you're just curious about how `tools:overrideLibrary` is used, it is a `AndroidManifest.xml` attribute:
Another stackOverflow question/ answer: [How do I use tools:overrideLibrary in a build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095077/how-do-i-use-toolsoverridelibrary-in-a-build-gradle-file)

---

If you need to support API levels 20 and below, you need to find an alternative to the Flutter camera plugin, because it uses the camera2 API. I wasn't able to find one, so you probably have to make your own.
[How to use Android's camera or camera2 API to support old and new API versions without deprecation notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272845/how-to-use-androids-camera-or-camera2-api-to-support-old-and-new-api-versions-w)